# Using cordova build android --release with debugging

Tags: android, cordova, debugging, build

I'm using cordova to build and sign my apk.

In my specific situation, I need to be able to debug a signed apk using cordova build android --release.

I've added `android:debuggable="true"` to the AndroidManifest.xml, however I still can't debug my application. I'm using intel crosswalk in my project (embedding the Chromium WebView).

Can you please help me out here?